# display jquery prettyPhoto lightbox in parent from iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, parent

I know this issue has been discussed before but I can't seem to get it to work. I have a master html page with an iframe on that page. I am using jquery prettyphoto and I was wondering how I can get the light box to display in the parent window when I click on the link in the iframe?

Please my code below:

Master Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Master Page</title> 
</head> 

<body> 
 <iframe src="iframe.html" width="300" height="300px" frameborder="0"></iframe> 
</body> 
</html>
```

iFrame Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>iframe</title>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    @import url("assets/css/infotech-iframes.css");
    @import url("assets/css/infotech-popup.css");
</style>

<script src="assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.popup.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <a href="assets/images/screenshots/campaign-setup-lg.png" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]"><img src="assets/images/screenshots/campaign-setup-sm.gif" /></a>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to edit the prettyPhoto.js source to push everything into the parent frame. I would start by modifying the references to

```
appendTo($('body'))
```

to something like

```
appendTo($('body', window.parent))
```

Comment: Hi,

Tried your suggestion but still get the same result of the lightbox displaying within the iFrame and not the parent window.

Thaks